# Where can I get graphics for startup screens?

Tags: graphics, language-agnostic

I really like to have some graphic on my startup/login screen when starting my applications.

In one of my past employments, we had this on startup/login screen:

**Image missing:** *Head bangs on computer*

Where do you get your graphics for this purpose, and what are your favorites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have an official logo for our core products, and in release, that's what we use for the splash screen.

During development, we put funny pictures that we find from around the internet into a folder on a shared network drive.  The debug build will randomly pick a picture from that folder, if it can access it, and use that as the splash screen.

Some favs: 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Seriously though, whatever you end up going with for your official splash screen, make sure you don't violate copyright, etc, etc...

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, I recently found this and am finding it very uplifting...

http://www.istockphoto.com/file_thumbview_approve/1132735/2/istockphoto_1132735-running-man.swf

Comment: I guess that comes from upcoming spring and my wish to resume jogging sessions after long winter sleep :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of using fotolia.com.  For a couple of dollars you get licensed, professional quality images and graphics.

Another good source for icons such as above is iconfinder.net.  There's tons of free for-business icons there.

Answer (score 1):

You should get a graphic designer to create a splash screen for your product. You should be careful not to use others' copyrighted imagery in your software, unless you know it is licensed under a non-restrictive license like one of the Creative Commons licenses. Make sure you understand and comply with whatever license your imagery has.

Comment: Even for internal you should pay for what you use. Those are someone's intellectual property.

Comment: @durilai: You know, you're right. You're probably not supposed to use copyrighted works for any commercial purpose, even internally. I'll edit to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Legally you can use a www.istockphoto.com